# c9.io-failed to preview web page

Tags: node.js, sails.js, cloud9-ide

I am working on sails js project in cloud9.io and getting this problem. There is no error in my code shown by console. I have mysql connection which is establishing well and also it shows phpmyadmin's home page but it is not showing my web page when I click to "preview with web server".

Comment: Could you paste in your code and any error messages that are showing up?

Comment: a screenshot image of the related error would be helpful indeed - please :-)

Comment: i am sorry i really don't know what code or error i have to show u because there is no error it's previewing just an empty page n developer's console saying resource not found.i have checked my routing too.is there any generic reason why it can happen?